QuickFix python for CQG
I am trying to connect to the CQG FIX API.  My python code works fine with StoneX.  However, the login for CQG requires some additional parameters:
SenderSubID = (value)
RawData = (value)

Although the FIX number code for these is included within the SWIG-generated quickfix.py, the actual variables are not:
SENDERCOMPID = cvar.SENDERCOMPID   (This variable is used)
SENDERSUBID = cvar.SENDERSUBID  (This line is MISSING)

This is also missing int the sessionsettings.h file.  When I add the appropriate lines to sessionsettings.h, the swig script "swig.sh" generates a new quickfix.py with the appropriate lines:
SENDERSUBID = cvar.SENDERSUBID

HOWEVER, when I try to include this new quickfix in the python program, I get the following error:

delete_SwigPyIterator  module not in _quickfix

I downgraded to Swig 3.0.10, which is the version that generated the original quickfix that works, and I get the same error message.
Any help with this problem would be much appreciated...
